# How to intuitively understand scattering cross section?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, scattering-cross-section

Suppose a QCD process considered in a leading order level, the production of ttbar. It happened in two ways,qqbar to ttbar and gluongluon to ttbar. I can compute the cross section for each ways, nevertheless, I still don't understand why bigger cross section means greater possibility, it's obvious that greater possibility means finding more events in a certain gathered data, but how can I connect scattering cross section and possibility together in an intuitive way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea of "scattering cross section" was an extension of the study of classical scattering problems. In rigid body scattering without long-range interaction forces, the probability of some randomly chosen beam particle hitting the target was proportional to the cross-sectional area of the target as seen from the perspective of the beam. Including interaction forces, we define a sort of "effective cross-sectional area" such that for a random particle, the probability of interaction is the same as the probability of hitting a target of that size in a rigid body scattering problem. We call this effective area the cross-section.

Comment: Indeed. The "problem" may be that the effecting cross section may be larger than the size of the particle.

Comment: @Pieter That's not so much a problem as it is a definition. For a lot of particle physics applications, we're treating things as point particles anyway